# Count occurrence of strings in JSON array

Tags: arrays, json

I have the JSON response below and I want to count the occurrence of string matches in the "ref_id" objects. But I have no idea where to start when looping through the array and counting the matches. Any help or recommendation where I should start would be appreciated

```
{
"tag": "checkthisServer",
"success": 1,
"error": 0,
"svd_ids": [
    {
        "ref_id": "f91e2651"
    },
    {
        "ref_id": "f91e2651"
    },
    {
        "ref_id": "ue87sr5d"
    },
    {
        "ref_id": "f91e2651"
    }
    {
        "ref_id": "ue87sr5d"
    }
]
}
```

Output should be:

```
f91e2651: 3
ue87sr5d: 2
```

Comment: Look up JSONArray.  Loop through and put initial result in Hashmap.  If ref_id is already in Hahsmap then increment value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it using `Collections.frequency` on ArrayList. so first get JSONArray from JSONObeject then convert it to ArrayList as:

```
JSONObject mainobj=new JSONObject("your json string");
// get svd_ids JSONArray
JSONArray json_array=mainobj.getJSONArray("svd_ids");

// get ArrayList from JSONArray

   ArrayList<String> listsvd_ids = new ArrayList<String>();  
   for (int i=0;i<json_array.length();i++){ 
    listsvd_ids.add(json_array.get(i).toString());
   } 

//  occurrence of f91e2651
int occur_f91e2651 = Collections.frequency(listsvd_ids, "f91e2651");
//  occurrence of ue87sr5d
int occur_ue87sr5d = Collections.frequency(listsvd_ids, "ue87sr5d");
//.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This : Here filterValues is your JSON

```
filterValues = filterValues.reduce((newObj, obj) => {
let value = 1;
if(newObj[obj[ref_id]]) {
   value = value + 1;
   newObj[obj[ref_id]] = obj[ref_id] + ' (' + value + ')';
} else {
    newObj[obj[ref_id]] = obj[ref_id] + ' (' + value + ')';
}            
return newObj;
}, {});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
JSONArray responseArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("svd_ids");
int countFirst = 0, countSecond = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < responseArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject obj = responseArray.getJSONObject(i);
    if (obj.optString("ref_id").equals("f91e2651") {
        countFirst = countFirst + 1;
    }
    if (obj.optString("ref_id").equals("ue87sr5d") {
        countSecond = countSecond + 1;
    }
}
```